# I would like to create stock-market on my RPG game. Any ideas on formulas?

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea what formulas I should use to create stock-market for my players that they could play it. I use php+mysql. Maybe you can throw any good ideas? I'll be grateful.

Comment: This isn't really programming-related so much as it is an exercise in economics.

Comment: I would say it's more of an exercise in algorithms. The formulas may end up coming from economics, but they also might not.

Comment: No formulas needed... just a random number generator. No one will be able to tell the difference. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (but not necessarily the best) way of implementing fluctuation in stock prices is by using a random walk, since it has been hypothesised that stock prices can be modelled using such a process. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk_hypothesis

So, `dp = rand(-1,1) * p * dt` where p is the stock price and dt is the time elapsed (probably in days).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is multiplayer, in addition to random walk, some consideration of supply and demand can be taken into account.  If more shares are bought than sold of a particular stock over a period, its value should go up slightly, and vice-versa.  This will increase volatility and perhaps make this portion of the game more exciting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowing buying and selling between players (and assuming you've already created the storage part), you just need to expose four methods and let the players define the economy:

```
Bid (stock, price) 
Offer (stock, price)   
Buy (stock, price)    
Sell (stock, price)
```

If the stocks already exist in your game, then you just need to let the players define what they want for theirs.